# Mirrored traffic not reaching iptables logging

Tags: iptables, port-mirroring

I want to log traffic details for every packet using IPTABLES on mirrored traffic coming from a switch on my interface em4 with `-j LOG` option. I saw a similar scenario [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/654384/filter-mirrored-port-traffic-using-iptables).

em4 is in promisc mode.
I'm using the following commands but the rule is not getting hit and I cannot see logs in `/var/log/messages`

```
tunctl -u root
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 em4
brctl addif br0 tap0
brctl setfd br0 0
brctl stp br0 off  
ifconfig br0 up
ifconfig eth0 up 0.0.0.0
ifconfig tap0 up 0.0.0.0
echo 0 > /sys/class/net/br0/bridge/ageing_time
echo 1 > /sys/devices/virtual/net/br0/bridge/nf_call_iptables
iptables -F
iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -j LOG
```

Comment: You say you're using interface `em4` but in the commands you've run I don't see that, only `eth0`. Did you also read the answer given in the question you've linked to?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly had written eth0 instead of em4 which I have updated now.
And yes, I have turned on the promiscuous mode of em4 as you can see here: 
     ``[root@snitch ~]# ifconfig em4
em4: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500``